# Android bring a widget on top of all other widgets

Tags: android

i'm trying to design this view with `RelativeLayout`

[Screen Shot](http://rupload.ir/upload/u8rhs193cal8i406wmru.png)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <com.pishguy.myapp.Libraries.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageAvatar"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/phone_contact_unchecked_checkbox"
        android:minHeight="22dp"
        android:minWidth="22dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageAvatar"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageAvatar"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

but i can't bring `checkbox` widget on top of `imageAvatar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change it's order inside parent layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/phone_contact_unchecked_checkbox"
        android:minHeight="22dp"
        android:minWidth="22dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true""/>
    <com.pishguy.myapp.Libraries.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageAvatar"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkbox/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `checkbox` cause of change `imageAvatar` position into RelativeLayout

Comment: and i can set `imageAvatar` to center

Comment: Yeah, u should change align attributes; pls check my updated answer.